# Why were the crowds cheering Caspian, Aslan and the others?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia

In *Prince Caspian*, the movie version at least, at the end after the great battle we get a city scene showing Caspian, 4 kings, Aslan and various Narnia creatures riding into the city, being cheered by what I think is an exclusively human crowd. But why are they cheering?

The way I understood the plot, those humans must be Telmars, in their minds sole rightful inhabitants of the land for many years now. The Narnian creatures started a rebellion against them – and their rightful crowned king gathered an army to fight them.

The way the beginning of the battle went, the average soldier must think that their king was betrayed and assassinated by Narnians, a despicable act.

During the battle various magical stuff happened and the lion-god of the enemy made sure the Telmar armies were defeated. Returning soldiers, those who survived at least, would have a terrible tale, surely not warming Caspian's image - if they were allowed to go home, that is, and if they were not the situation would be even worse.

What happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the book, the descendants of the original humans in Narnia are still around, and are living in the towns and villages throughout Narnia. They live with and have integrated with the Telmarine society, however, they still pass down the stories of the 4 king/queens and of Aslan. At the end of the battle Aslan gives all of the Telmarines a choice to either go back were their from (through a gateway back to earth) or to stay and live peacefully in Narnia. So your crowd at the end of the movie, is  descendants of old Narnia, and those Telmarines who choose to stay in Narnia, and therefore accept Aslan.

Comment: In the movie the choice scene happens in a city - the city I'm talking about, and the announcement of that choice is probably why they're there.

Comment: yeh i cant remember the movies as well, also the X-king no body liked and was cruel to the normal people, so just having caspian as king was enough for cheering.